# Convergence of a sequence of minima of a family of optimal control problems

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

Let $(\lambda_k)$ be an unbounded and increasing sequence of real numbers, and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \ \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be sufficiently smooth such that $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t))$ has an unique solution for each $x(0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that the optimal control problem

$$
J_k = \min \int_{0}^{t_f} L(x(s),u(s))\, ds + \lambda_k \| x(t_f) - x_f\|^2 
$$
subject to
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= f(x(t),u(t)), \quad t\in[0, t_f],\\
x(0) &= x_0, 
\end{align}
$$
has an unique solution for each $\lambda_k$.

If the optimal control problem
$$
J = \min \int_{0}^{t_f} L(x(s),u(s))\, ds 
$$
subject to
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= f(x(t),u(t)), \quad t\in[0, t_f],\\
x(0) &= x_0, \\
x(t_f) &= x_f
\end{align}
$$

has also an unique solution, it is true that $J_k \rightarrow J$?